# Motherboard Lights On but Nothing Else Gets Power

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer, asus

So after getting my brother's build pc shipped to me by UPS, the computer stopped working. It was working before hand and now I'm trying to find out what went wrong during shipping. When plugged in the Motherboard receives power and shines it's RGB LEDs but when I go to turn on via the power button (there is no on-board motherboard power button) the LED on the Power button doesn't shine and there's no power going through the computer except on the Motherboard. No fans, no RAM, no GPU, nothing receives power.
I've looked through the computer to see if any wiring got loose and made sure they were in there securely (minus the case fans, unhooked those because they're not needed rn) and even inspected the pins on the F Panel Connector to see if they got bent or something. I'm thinking it's one of three things:

1. The F Panel Wire Connected to the case broke.
2. The Case itself broke, so like the button to turn on the power isn't working anymore.
3. Worst Case Scenario: The Motherboard broke.

I've never built a PC before and I have no idea what could be the true problem and may not even be one of the problems listed. I would absolutely love it if someone could help me with some straight answers. Here are the list of Parts that I know of:

Motherboard: ASUS TUF Gaming X570-Plus (Wi-fi)

Processor : AMD Ryzen

GPU : GEFORCE GTX 1660 Series

RAM : 12 or 16 Gig Trident Z Neo RGB DDR4 Memory

Case: NZXT H510/ H510i Compact Mid-Tower ATX Case.

Help!

Comment: Power problem would usually point to the PSU, even more indicated if the fans are not working.

Comment: Even when the Motherboard itself is receiving power? @harrymc

Comment: The fans are the best indicator for bad PSU, since they start at POST.

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1dcJ0QyAE jump-start PSU test. If the PSU fires up and stays powered on, you can move onto the next piece of the puzzle.

Comment: When I had this problem with my MSI Godlike motherboard it was DOA.  I had to send it to MSi under its warranty

Comment: Have you tried to short the power switch pins on the FP Connector rather than use the power switch?  Is the CPU power cable plugged in as well as the main 24pin cable?